# How to convert simple $http with callback to use promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm trying to wrap my head around promises in angular and i have the example below that I'd like to convert to use promises so hopefully it will help me go "Ah ha!".

All the examples that I find on the interwebs are using services/factories/etc and I just want to know the best way to make something simple like this use promises.

```
angular.module('web').controller('CardsCtrl',function($scope, $http, $q){

    // Don't worry about how the variable "users" gets populated, let's just say it came into magical existance from a unicorn's horn.
    $scope.users = users;

    // Loop through all the users
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.users .length; i++) {

      // THIS FAILS BECAUSE THE LOOP FINISHES BEFORE THE 1ST GET REQUEST FINISHES SO WE CAN'T REFERENCE THE I VARIABLE
      $http.get('http://uifaces.com/api/v1/random', function(face) {
        $scope.users[i].face = face.image_urls.mini;
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: are you using a resfull api? if so $resource service is designed for that

Comment: No i'm just using one endpoint. http://uifaces.com/api

Comment: well i am not sure of this, becasue I normally use $resource service but you should try it. what I usually do is `$resource('myurl').$promise()` that will convert your requesto to promisse, then you can use `.then()` if you need it

Comment: this is usefull https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-chained-promises

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is not an issue with promises. It's just the classical "closure in a loop" issue.

Fix it like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.users .length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    $http.get('http://uifaces.com/api/v1/random', function(face) {
      $scope.users[i].face = face.image_urls.mini;
    });
  }(i));
}
```

Comment: Well i'd like to learn promises so i'm curious how you would convert this to use promises. But i am also interested in having you elaborate on this function inside the loop that you have.

Comment: @Catfish w.r.t the closure issue, just go there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: @Catfish for the promises issue, you should first have an easier example: have some callback hell to transform to promises. Well simpler. Sequences are not hard with promises, but they're definitely harder than the simple stuff you should go through first.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I'd write it:

```
 $q.all($scope.users.map(function(user){
      return $http.get('http://uifaces.com/api/v1/random').then(function(face){
           return user.face = face.image_urls.mini;
      });
 })).then(function(results) {
    // results contains the images actually used, so you can use it here too
 });
```

Comment: I believe `map` isn't sequential, is it? What's `$q` equivalent for this?

Comment: Using .all with array map